# Convert YUV imageformat to PNG

Tags: android, yuv

I was struggeling to get YuvImage to a png imageformat on an Android 5.0.1 device where the png showed up as green images. On a Android 5.1.1 this did not happend, and the images was showing just fine.
After some time I found out that there is a bug in Android 5.0.1 which makes the images that are converted appear green. This was fixed in Android 5.1.1

However, does anyone know about a solution in order to make this work on devices that has not got this fix?

Comment: Are you using the Camera 2 API or the old one?

Comment: @silvaren I am using the Camera 2 API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to workaround the bug because in my experience the images are already green when generated by the system, and it is not a problem of the conversion to PNG.

I see that you are using the Camera 2 API from your comment response, and since you are using YUV format I believe you are trying to save images from the continuous feed from the camera (as opposed from full resolution picture taking). If that is the case, I'll suggest using the older Camera API if at all possible, as I haven't seen a device that does not work when capturing preview images in YUV format (NV21), which can easily converted to a PNG, although having to go through a JPEG step:

```
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(nv21bytearray, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, os);
byte[] jpegByteArray = os.toByteArray();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegByteArray, 0, jpegByteArray.length);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/imagename.png");
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

with `nv21bytearray` being the NV21 byte array returned by the old camera API [onPreviewFrame(...)](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html#onPreviewFrame(byte[],%20android.hardware.Camera)) method.

Comment: Added the deprecated Camera API. So only devices using 5.1.1 and above will be using the Camera2 API.

Comment: This is not necessarily a good choice since JPEG is lossy compression. You'll have to convert the YUV data into RGB by implementing the pixel conversion formula and then save it with `Bitmap` class.